# datetime can't handle overflow

Tags: python, datetime, csv, python-2.7

I wrote a Python script that basically strips down a `.csv` file generated from EXCEL (actually the OpenOffice variant but it's basically the same thing).

The `.csv` includes timings for a light. One set of data contains light on, the other contains light off. I'm trying to make a script that takes both times, converts them, and then spits out a subtraction problem telling me the total number of hours the light was on.

The kicker is that sometimes the light is turned on at 0800 and then turned off at 0100 the next morning. My script does all processing fine before the first time this happens in my data set and then quits as soon as it hits a snag.

A second question: The way I have my code set up, the first three numbers in the date-time numbers are assigned to a day of the year by `%j`.  Will this break when I have more than 365 values?  What's an alternative?

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\Programming\Python scripts\Actually useful\excel_strip.py", line 55, in <module>
    print(datetime.strptime(offlst[idx], '%j%H%M'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 8
```

Below is the code in question. The lines with comments next to them are the relevant parts.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

inc = 0
inc2 = 0
inc3 = 0
inc4 = 0
inc5 = 1
inc6 = 1
inc7 = 0
datelst = []
templst = []
onlst = []
offlst = []
time_diff = []
waterlst = []

path = raw_input("Enter the pathname for your .csv file. (e.g. C:\Myfolder\myfile.csv: ")

out = open(path, 'rb')
data = csv.reader(out)
data = [row for row in data]

for row in data:
    if row[inc].startswith('DATE'):
        loadlist = row[inc + 1]
        datestr = loadlist[:10]
        datelst.append(datestr)
    elif row[inc2].startswith('TEMP'):
        tempstr = row[inc2 + 1]
        templst.append(tempstr)
    elif row[inc3].startswith('LIGHT ON'): #This block takes the light on times and writes them all to a list with padding for a day value
        onstr = row[inc3 + 1]
        if onstr != 'N/A':
            onlst.append(format(inc5, '03d') + onstr)
            inc5+=1
        else:
            onlst.append(onstr)
            inc5+=1
    elif row[inc4].startswith('LIGHT OFF'): #Same as above for light off times
        offstr = row[inc4 + 1]
        if offstr != 'N/A':
            offlst.append(format(inc6, '03d') + offstr)
            inc6+=1
        else:
            offlst.append(offstr)
            inc6+=1
    elif row[inc7].startswith('H2O AMNT (mL)'):
        waterstr = row[inc7 + 1]
        waterlst.append(waterstr)

for idx, val in enumerate(onlst): #The following block tries to iterate over the list to make times that can be subtracted by one another.
    if onlst[idx] != 'N/A':
        print(datetime.strptime(onlst[idx], '%j%H%M'))
        print(datetime.strptime(offlst[idx], '%j%H%M'))
        light_on = datetime.strptime(onlst[idx], '%j%H%M')
        light_off = datetime.strptime(offlst[idx], '%j%H%M')
        time_diff.append(str(light_off - light_on))
    else:
        time_diff.append('N/A')

for idx, val in enumerate(time_diff):
    if time_diff[idx].startswith('-'):
        loadlist2 = time_diff[idx]
        timestring = loadlist2[8:]
        time_diff[idx] = timestring

out = open('newlog.csv','wb')
output = csv.writer(out)
output.writerow(datelst)
output.writerow(templst)
output.writerow(time_diff)
output.writerow(waterlst)
out.close()
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but make sure you don't reuse file handles. Currently, `out` is used to open the input file and the output file. IMHO, the easiest way to handle everything related to file IO is with the `with` statement, as in `with open(path,'rb') as out: data = csv.reader(out)` and so on

Comment: @pnuts Will this work if I have 0100 the next day written at 2500? I'd rather not rewrite all the entries in the EXCEL file

Comment: How do I convert the values I have to serial to test this? That in and of itself sounds like a task. I have to convert the dates and times since they're in separate cells, concatenate the cells, and then I can manipulate them in python...

Comment: @darthbith Thanks I didn't catch that.